# Where is com.google.android:android:jar:4.4.2_r3?

Tags: java, android, maven

I'm trying to install [ListViewAnimations](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) on my local maven repository. So I cloned the git repo and I ran `mvn install`. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with that error :

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project lib-core: Could not resolve
>   dependencies for project
>   com.nhaarman.listviewanimations:lib-core:apklib:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   com.google.android:android:jar:4.4.2_r3,
>   com.android.support:support-annotations:jar:19.1.0: Failure to find
>   com.google.android:android:jar:4.4.2_r3 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central

I don't understand how to resolve this :

- The latest version of `com.google.android:android` at maven central is [4.1.1.4](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.android%22%20AND%20a%3A%22android%22)
- I could use the [maven SDK deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer), but it install `android:android:4.4.2_r3`, not `com.google.android:android:jar:4.4.2_r3`...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to read [this](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/wiki/Contributing-%28Maven%29) page.